# CSS-Background image not full screen (uikit)

Tags: html, css, uikit, background-image

Got some trouble with my background-picture with uikit.
Would be nice if you have a quick solution for me.

```
body {   
  background-image: url("bg.png");   
  background-repeat: no-repeat;    
  background-attachment: fixed;      
}
```

Here an image of that failure

[image]

Comment: The background image is visible in that failure result.

Comment: Yes, it is. I want that backgroud to fill the whole screen and not only the part behind the card.

Answer (score 0):

How look its image?

In your screenshot you already have background image on `<body>`

If you want set background on card, just use correct css selector

**Update:**

For filling background, set `background-repeat: repeat;`

Comment: Nah, I want that 1920x1080 picture in the background behind that card... Any ideas?

Comment: The backgroud is not filling the whole screen, but only the part behind the card.

Comment: Background not filling because you set `background-repeat: no-repeat;`, just change on `background-repeat: repeat;`

Comment: No that wasnt the problem, because the background is 1920x1080 so it would fill anyways. The problem was, that "uk-container" from uikit was changing the dimensions of the body... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because you not give size to body, browser depended on size card, set size to body to appear background img full screen.

```
body {  
  padding : 0px ;
  margin : 0px ;
  width : 100hv ;
  height : 100hv;
  background-image: url("bg.png")  no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;       
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You must set your height with

```
uk-height-viewport="offset-top: true"
```

This will set your height with 100vh if it does not have any element on top of it.
You can see example here:

https://codepen.io/e2a4/pen/wvJyqKx